# Let obstructed element receive mouse press

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm having some problems getting the correct behavior for my WPF user control.
I use a listbox to show elements for a databound `ObservableCollection` in a datatemplate defined like this

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ToolNodeVM:NodeViewModel}">
    <Thumb>
        <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border Width="160" Margin="0,0,10,0" ClipToBounds="False">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding NodeName}" Foreground="White"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Thumb.Template>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="DragDelta">
                <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                            Command="{Binding DragDeltaCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Thumb>
</DataTemplate>
```

If I press on the text block, the thumb receives the mouse event and the `DragDeltaCommand` databound command is executed, and if there is no element under the mouse (within the `Border` the Listbox recieves the command and sets the item as the selected one and highlights it with the default blue color.

Eventually I would like to give the item a background, but this would mean the listbox item would never be selected because there would be something in the way... the background of the `Border`.

How would I proceed in order to let the item always become selected, giving the mouse press event to both the listbox and to the thumb with its drag delta command?